# How can i get only the new files in git from other branch

Tags: git, version-control

I have `TEST` branch and then i have `master` branch.

I have folder called  `DATA` with subfolders and files.

Now in my master i have

1. new files which are not in TEST
2. Files modified both in TEST AND master
3. files in master but deleted in TEST

Now i only want to update TEST branch with new files from master branch so that everything else unchnaged for TEST branch but new files should be there.

I could do that easily with `rsync` but just thinking if that could be done in `git`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be a bit careful with this as there are different answers to similar, but not exactly-the-same, questions.  For instance suppose the commit history looks like this:

```
A - B - C   <-- master
  \
    D - E   <-- TEST
```

Here `master` and `TEST` start with a common commit, `A`, and then diverge.  Let's suppose that the common commit `A` has these files (in directory `DATA/` if you like, but I'll just name the files):

```
file_A1
file_A2
```

Suppose further that commit `B` adds `file_B1` but deletes `file_A2`.  Then, commit `C` adds `file_C1` and modifies `file_A1` slightly.

This means if you `git checkout master` you will get the three files (A1, B1, and C1) with the modified `file_A1` contents.

Now suppose commit `D` modifies `file_A1` and adds `file_B1` and `file_D1`.  Then commit `E` removes `file_B1` and adds nothing else.

This means if you `git checkout TEST` you will get three files (A1, A2, and D1) with the modified `file_A1` contents (which may be modified differently from the version in commit `C`, or could be the same as the contents in commit `C`).

When you ask about "files in `TEST` that are not in `master`", does `file_A2` count?  It's there if you `git checkout TEST`; it's not there if you `git checkout master`; but it *was* there in the common starting point, commit `A`.

When you wonder about "files modified in both": clearly `file_A1` was modified in both.  But what if the change was identical in both, so that `file_A1` has the same contents regardless of which branch is checked out.  Is that "modified in both", or not?

What git needs you to do to answer such questions is to choose whether to compare two *specific revisions*, or to consider something more like a three-way merge (what you'd get if you attempted to merge `TEST` and `master` using their merge-base, revision `A`, as a starting point).

---

```
git diff <options> master TEST
```

This will compare commit `C` (what `master` points-to, i.e., the "tip" of the master branch) vs commit `E` (the tip of branch `TEST`).  So you'll compare the two `file_A1`s, and see that commit `E` has `file_A2` and `file_D1` and lacks `file_B1`.

The `<options>` part here may be empty, or may be as described below.

---

```
mergebase=$(git merge-base master TEST)
git diff <options> $mergebase master
git diff <options> $mergebase TEST
```

This does two separate diffs, of the merge-base (commit `A`) against `master`, and of the merge-base against `TEST`.

The first diff will show you that on branch `master`, the change from `A` to `C` is to modify `file_A1`, delete `file_A2`, add `file_B1`, and add `file_C1`.

This is the kind of operation git uses to figure out how to do a branch merge.  In fact, there's a special syntax for running `git diff` against the merge-base of two branches, against the tip of one of those two branches:

```
git diff <options> TEST...master  # three dots
```

This does the same as the first diff (`git diff <options> $mergebase master`).  To compare the merge-base to the tip of branch `TEST`:

```
git diff <options> master...TEST  # again, three dots
```

---

As for `<diff options>`, if you're not interested in the different *contents* of files, the obvious option to start with is `--name-status`, which prints the names and status-es of the files, and `--no-renames`, to turn off rename detection (unless you *want* rename detection, in which case, add `-M` instead).

Files will show up as added, deleted, or modified (`A`, `D`, and `M` status respectively) in terms of the change between the two trees you'd get if you checked out the commits chosen by the diff.  There are more possibilities here though: `T` occurs if a regular file is replaced with a symlink or vice versa (and more special cases with submodules); `C` (plus a numeric similarity value) occurs if you add `--find-copies-harder` and/or `-C` options; and `R` (plus a numeric value just like `C`) occurs with rename detection.  The `C` and `R` cases print not only the status and filename, but also the "origin file name".

You can add `--diff-filter` to select only particular occurrences: `--diff-filter=A`, for instance, will select only those files whose status is `A` (added).